# how i can solve coupled time dependent differential equation and plot their solution with other variable not with time

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions

```
w1 = 1;
w2 = 1;
gma1 = 0.1;
g1 = 1;
amp1 = 0.5;
mu=0.03;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{q1'[t] - w1*p1[t] == 0, 
     q2'[t] - w2*p2[t] == 0, 
    p1'[t] + w1*q1[t] + gma1*p1[t] - g1*amp1 - mu*q2[t] == 0, 
p2'[t] + w2*q2[t] + gma1*p2[t] - g1*amp1 - mu*q1[t] == 0, 
q1[0] == 1, q2[0] == 1, p1[0] == 1, p2[0] == 0}, {q1, q2, p1, 
p2}, {t, 0, 50}, {q1, q2}];
Plot[Evaluate[p1[t][50] /. sol], {q1, 0, 3}]
```

I am trying to Plot between variable 'p' and 'q'. don't know how it will be possible. If anyone can solve this is most welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "Plot between variable 'p' and 'q'"?

Comment: 'p' is the mean of p1 and p2. 'q' is the mean of q1 and q2.

Comment: 1. Still, the question is unclear. Do you need a 2D plot or a 3D plot? What's the independent variable(s)? What's the dependent variable(s)? Anyway, you may want to read the document of `ParametricPlot`. 2. You're not using `ParametricNDSolve` correctly, please check the document carefully. 3. Definition of `mu` is missing.

Comment: i need 2D plot. p and q both are dependent variable on time. and value of mu=0.03;

Comment: I only have these equations and i want to plot between 'p' and 'q'. where p and q are mean value of p1,p2 and q1,q2 respectively. and both are dependent on time. you can vary time to any value. i need a plot.

Comment: Why do you say "between"? Are you looking for `Filling` option? Once again, please press F1 and read the document of the functions I mentioned above. Reading the document is the first thing one should learn when using _Mathematica_.

Comment: Parameter mu isn't defined!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann mu=0.03

Comment: You should edit your question to include the value of `mu` and other clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right you try to solve 4 differential equations depending on a parameter mu and you try to plot the result (q1+q2)/2 over (p1+p2)/2!?

If so try

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{q1'[t] - w1*p1[t] == 0, 
q2'[t] - w2*p2[t] == 0, 
p1'[t] + w1*q1[t] + gma1*p1[t] - g1*amp1 - mu*q2[t] == 0, 
p2'[t] + w2*q2[t] + gma1*p2[t] - g1*amp1 - mu*q1[t] == 0, 
q1[0] == 1, q2[0] == 1, p1[0] == 1, p2[0] == 0}, {q1, q2, p1, 
p2}, {t, 0, 50}, mu];

Manipulate[
ParametricPlot[{(sol[mu][[1]][t] + sol[mu][[2]][t])/2, (sol[mu][[3]][t] + sol[mu][[4]][t])/2}, {t, 0, 50},AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {(p1 + p2)/2, (q1 + q2)/2}]
, {{mu, 0.03}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much.. ohhh sorry sorry the value of mu=0.03.

Comment: if i want to fill colour in between what should i do? also i want 't' in place of mu.

Comment: sorry, i want to plot the same graph but you have plotted this with 'mu' but mu=0.03, in place of 'mu' i need time. rest all is fine. now please try once more.

Comment: `mu=0.03`is a constant value in my plot. The curve parameter is `t` . At this point I think it's up to you to try something  (and/or clarify your question!)

Comment: ohhh thankyou now i have understood.. thanks